# Strange warnings when running image_view

Tags: macos-mountain-lion, ros-groovy, image-view, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run image_view, it works, but I get a lot of strange warnings on the command line:

```
[kevin@tardis ros_sandbox]$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/opencv_cam/camera

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:591): GLib-CRITICAL **: void g_once_init_leave(volatile void *, gsize): assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: void g_type_add_interface_static(GType, GType, const GInterfaceInfo *): assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gtype.c:2720: You forgot to call g_type_init()

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: void g_type_interface_add_prerequisite(GType, GType): assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(process:591): GLib-CRITICAL **: void g_once_init_leave(volatile void *, gsize): assertion `result != 0' failed

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: void g_type_add_interface_static(GType, GType, const GInterfaceInfo *): assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(process:591): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid uninstantiatable type `(null)' in cast to `<invalid>'

(process:591): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: instance of invalid non-instantiatable type `(null)'

(process:591): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: gulong g_signal_connect_data(gpointer, const gchar *, GCallback, gpointer, GClosureNotify, GConnectFlags): assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
^C[kevin@tardis ros_sandbox]$
```

Not sure if it is related to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/53155/building-image_view-fails-on-osx/) question or not. Any ideas how to fix this?

ROS Groovy

OSX 10.8, Homebrew

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53278/strange-warnings-when-running-image_view/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-01-24**:
You might want to try rqt_image_view which is based on Qt instead and should provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure where in the image_view code this comes from, but if memory serves, similar errors come up on Linux, and it might be that you can simply ignore those warnings.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0